# manipulating helper output before print

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like some ideas for me to handle an output of a helper.

This output I want to manipulate:

Output Html:

```
<div data-yotpo-element-id="2" class="yotpo bottomLine yotpo-medium" data-product-id="800270">.....</div>
```

Generated by this helper:

```
$this->helper('yotpo')->showBottomline($this, $_product);
```

Helper:

```
public function showBottomline($thisObj, $product = null, $print = true) {

        $res = $this->renderYotpoProductBlock($thisObj, 'yotpo-bottomline', $product);
        if ($print == false) {
            return $res;
        }
    }
```

I need to do something like this:

```
$input = $this->helper('yotpo')->showBottomline($this, $_product);
preg_match('....something', $input, $output);
echo $output[1]; //catch a piece of the code generated by helper
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the helper uses "renderYotpoProductBlock" and passes in some parameters.   I assume your best course of action if you wish to update the output of that function is to overwrite that class and function and change the output.

Intercepting it and replacing html like you are trying to do is not a very neat and clean solution and is vulnerable to break as the code changes.

Comment: This is the function called by showBottomline:
http://infinit.io/_/SmbTc7k

  I tried to return the block as variable instead of echo, but gives error.